# How to determine a method signature dynamically when throwing custom exceptions?

Tags: java, reflection, exception

I am following a standard that requires me to log the class#method that originates an exception for easy debugging from our UI. Without pulling the logs I know what method spawned the exception and can (usually) easily find the root cause.

However, I would like a dynamic way of determining the method signature because I am currently hard-coding it everywhere I am throwing an exception. Is there a better way.

```
 @Service
 public class UserService {

     @Autowired
     private UserRepository userRepository;

     public User findUser(Long id){

          if(id == null || id < 1){
               throw new BadRequestException("UserService#findUser", String.format(
                                             "Invalid Id: %d", id));
          }

          User user = userRepository.findOne(id);

          if(user == null){
               throw new DataNotFoundException("UserService#findUser", String.format(
                                               "Can't Find User for Id: %d", id));
          }
          return user;
     }
 }
```

--

The goal is that I can create any custom exception and within that constructor I can infer the method signature by where the exception was created from.

```
 public BadRequestException(String issue){
      super(String.format("%s | Bad Request | %s", <<signature>>, issue);
 }
```

--

```
 UserService class --> findUser method --> BadRequest("UserService#findUser")
 UserService class --> createUser method --> BadRequest("UserService#createUser")
```

Comment: Shouldn't you rely on logs more (it can also have reference to class and line number where exception was raised.) ? The UI messages are supposedly non technical and user friendly. Also a clear message should point you whats missing / unexpected thing occurred.

Comment: We use logs as a second step if further investigation is needed. The user friendly message is the second argument provided in the exception. "Invalid Id" or "Can't Find User", etc.

Comment: Your users must be very cool/techie otherwise they question each word of anything which is prompted - forget about the class name/method name. :) Anyways good luck with your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could introduce a helper method that retrieves the method and the class names from the current thread :

```
private static MethodAndClassName retrieveMethodAndClassName() {
       StackTraceElement[] allStackTraces = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
       StackTraceElement currentMethod = allStackTraces[2]; 
       return new MethodAndClassName(currentMethod.getMethodName(), currentMethod.getClassName());      
}
```

Note that the method invocations are stacked.   I get the third last nested call (`allStackTraces[2]`) because  the last call (`allStackTraces[0]`) is `Thread.getStackTrace()`, the before last call  (`allStackTraces[1]`) is `retrieveMethodAndClassName()` and the before before last call (`allStackTraces[2]`) is what you look for : the method that invoked `retrieveMethodAndClassName()`.

`MethodAndClassName` is a custom class that defines needed information to trace :

```
public class MethodAndClassName {

    private String method;
    private String clazz;

    public MethodAndClassName(String method, String clazz) {
        this.method = method;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public String getMethodName() {
        return method;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

And in your client code use it such as :

```
 public User findUser(Long id){

      if(id == null || id < 1){             
           throw new BadRequestException(ReflectionHelper.retrieveMethodAndClassName(), String.format(
                                         "Invalid Id: %d", id));
      }

      User user = userRepository.findOne(id);

      if(user == null){
           throw new DataNotFoundException(ReflectionHelper.retrieveMethodAndClassName(), String.format(
                                           "Can't Find User for Id: %d", id));
      }
      return user;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Throwable.getStackTrace(). This will return an array of StackTraceElement, and the first entry will point to where the the Throwable was instantiated.